# sudo inside docker (on fedora) ask for password, on host it doesn't ask password

Tags: docker, sudoers

I am testing something in docker, it requires sudo without entering password, I added required entries in /etc/sudoers. After that in host it doesn't ask for password. But in case of docker it still ask for password. BTW, I am running fedora 24 in VirtualBox VM on a Fedora 24 host.

Here is the details...

```
abc@webster $ sudo bash

root@webster $ cat /etc/sudoers
## Sudoers allows particular users to run various commands as
...
...
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere 
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

%users ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL)   ALL
abc      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
#abc      ALL=(ALL)       ALL


abc@webster $ id
uid=1000(abc) gid=1000(abc) groups=1000(abc),10(wheel),100(users),977(docker),1001(admin) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023


abc@fc-docker $ sudo bash
[sudo] password for abc:
```

Comment: The container/image has its own `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: Thanks @tkausl. I just noticed it doesn't accept the sudo password as well. It asks for it 3 times and throws this error "sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts" I changed the password to very simple one and still it throws same issue. BTW, the fedora 24 is a VirtualBox VM.

Comment: Hi @tkausl, I tried a different way and solved the problem. I used to log in to docker as " docker exec -it --user abc fc-docker bash ", when I removed the user part and logged in like, " docker exec -it fc-docker bash ", I logged in as root. Then I modified /etc/sudoers to NO PASSWORD. Not its working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as an answer for more clarity. 
Docker instance had its own /etc/sudoers. Which need to be updated to allow sudo without password. Login to docker instance as 
" docker exec -it fc-docker bash ", you will be logged in as root. Then add
"abc      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" to /etc/sudoers/. Logout & login back, we can do sudo without password.

Comment: This doesn't address how to do it as part of the Dockerfile. See https://superuser.com/questions/1296533/sudo-inside-docker-on-fedora-ask-for-password-on-host-it-doesnt-ask-password#answer-1491777 for the command to modify the `sudoers` file, when there is no interactive terminal, such as in a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I setup a non-root user with passworsdless access to the sudo group using the base image of `ubuntu:18.04`:

```
RUN \
    groupadd -g 999 foo && useradd -u 999 -g foo -G sudo -m -s /bin/bash foo && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## **Removed the include directive** ##"/g' && \
    echo "foo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
    echo "Customized the sudoers file for passwordless access to the foo user!" && \
    echo "foo user:";  su - foo -c id
```

What happens with the above code:

- The user and group `foo` is created.
- The user `foo` is added to the both the `foo` and `sudo` group.
- The `uid` and `gid` is set to the value of `999`.
- The home directory is set to `/home/foo`.
- The shell is set to `/bin/bash`.
- The `sed` command does inline updates to the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow `foo` and `root` users passwordless access to the `sudo` group.
- The `sed` command disables the `#includedir` directive that would allow any files in subdirectories to override these inline updates.